# Quit bein' so blockin'

Tags: discussion, support, close-reasons, stackexchange, stackoverflow

I think Stack Exchange is too strict on closing and deleting questions. Perfectly feasible questions are marked as low-quality, too broad, or "unclear what you're asking." Are we really going too far with this?

I decided to test it out and see if those so-called "bad" questions are actually unsalvageable. I asked some "going-to-get-closed-if-this-were-on-SE" questions on several third-party Q&A and forum websites. It turns out that I got pretty good and helpful answers to the questions I asked (even Quora), even though they'd be closed and deleted if they were asked on Stack Exchange.

Examples of users' questions that Stack Exchange thinks are "really bad," yet were allowed when I asked them on other Q&A and forum sites:

---

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30878687

  Stack Exchange: not answered, closed, deleted.

  Yahoo Answers: received helpful answers, stayed open.

---

- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297438

  Stack Exchange: down-voted, closed, deleted.

  Ask.MetaFilter: received helpful answers, stayed open.

---

- [Computer randomly turning off](https://superuser.com/questions/1090551)

  Stack Exchange: not answered, down-voted, about to get closed.

  Yahoo Answers: suggested possible solutions, stayed open.

---

Sure, forums tend to be more spammy, but they aren't so strict in moderating the hell out of users' posts. Stack Exchange is definitely more professional, but I prefer a site where stuff doesn't get closed as often.

Why doesn't Stack Exchange allow questions that most other Q&A and forum sites would allow? I know Stack Exchange is not a forum, but those forums give users more freedom in what kinds of questions they can ask that aren't going to get closed and deleted.

Quit bein' so blockin'

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this doesn't concern Super User

Comment: Why are you complaining on su meta? 2 of your 3 examples are nothing to do with su.

Comment: You know why they didn't get closed/deleted on other Q&A and forum sites? Because they're not Stack Exchange. Quit bein' so derogatorily comparative.